# jquery undefined error on one element but not the other

Tags: jquery

I have a function that gets the id's of all the checked and unchecked checkboxes then hides or shows the element depending if it's checked or not.  My problem is that I'm getting:

TypeError: upperPos[this] is undefined
upperPos[this].hide();

but Im not getting this error on upperPos[this].show();
(and the elements appear as they should)

jquery:

```
$('body').on('change', '.optionForm', function() {
    var formId      = $(this).attr('id'),
        checked     = new Array();
        unchecked   = new Array();
    $('#' + formId + ' input:checked').each(function() {
        checked.push($(this).attr('id'));
    });
    $('#' + formId + ' input:not(:checked)').each(function() {
        unchecked.push($(this).attr('id'));
    });
    console.log(checked);
    $.each(checked, function() {
        upperPos[this].show();/*This does not have an error*/
    });
    console.log(unchecked);
    $.each(unchecked, function() {
        upperPos[this].hide();/*This is error*/
    });
});
```

Both arrays are being populated correctly.

upperPos[] contains an array of raphael objects.  The id's of the checkboxes correspond to the raphael objects and the function is supposed to hide/show them accordingly.

I would appreciate any help on why Im getting this error. If you need any additional info, please let me know.

Thanks, 
Adam

jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/adam123/Jw9h5/60/

For some reason the fiddle works, but my code does not.

Comment: What does `uppserPos` array contain ?

Comment: `.show()` is method available on a `jQuery` object . So I assume `uppserPos[this]` returns a jQuery object. And it's a good chance that none of the items in the form are checked , that might be the reason you don't see the error in the first `each` loop

Comment: @Sushanth yes, returns an object. But I'm not understanding why .show() is working but the .hide() is not.  Both are getting objects from the same array.

Comment: It is difficult to suggest anything without taking a look at the object and a bit of `HTML`

Comment: @Sushanth--I edited the question to what the upperPos[] array contains.  I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simple means that that object is not present in the  `upperPos` array.

so `upperPos[this]` is undefined for a specific item in the array . And you are not supposed to use `this` here as the **checked** and **unchecked** array is an array of strings.

Try this

```
$.each(checked, function(i, val) {
   upperPos[val] && upperPos[val].show();
});
console.log(unchecked);

$.each(unchecked, function(i, val) {
   upperPos[val] && upperPos[val].hide();
});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/ shows an example that if there is an array on strings, which array checked and unchecked are I should use this.  Is that correct?

Comment: From the docs `(The value can also be accessed through the this keyword, but Javascript will always wrap the this value as an Object even if it is a simple string or number value.) `

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying.  I updated the question with a jsFiddle, but like I noted, the fiddle works, so now Im even more perplexed.

Comment: Your answer works!  Why does upperPos[val] && upperPos[val] work correctly?

Comment: It works because you are only applying the method if the `upperPos[val]` has a value

Answer (score 0):

May suggest you change to this ? unless you need the arrays for something else, let me know and I edit:

```
$('body').on('change', '.optionForm', function() {
    var formId      = $(this).attr('id'),

    $('#' + formId + ' input:checked').each(function() {        
        $(this).show();
    });
    $('#' + formId + ' input:not(:checked)').each(function() {
            $(this).hide();
    });

});
```

Comment: I don't think he wants to `show or hide the checkboxes`, The OP wants to show some other element based on the checkbox condition

Comment: You might be right, is really hard to tell without context or HTML